# Log4 logging HTTP responses with HEX codes

Tags: java, logging, log4j, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

The HTTP client requests are logged in regular ASCII, but the responses are getting logged in hex codes.  I set up my log4j file just like another application that doesn't have this problem.

```
httpclient.wire.content >> </soap:Envelope>
...
httpclient.wire.content << "[0x1f][0x8b][0x8][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0]}[0x93][0xc1]N[0xc3]0[0xc][0x86][0xef]<E[0xe9][0xbd]M[0xcb][0xc4][0xa5]*E m[0x82][0x3]Lb[0xbc]@XM[0x89][0xd4]&!N[0xd3][0x8d][0xa7]G[0xed][0x9a]-[0xe9][0xd6][0xdd][0xe2][0xdf][0x9f][0xed]8vr[0x14]TfKn[0xa0][0x16][0x12][0x82]]Ss[0xcc]z[0xed]![0xfc][0xd1]Zf[0x84]t][0x17]w[0x8b]X[0xa8][0x8a][0xdc]%[0xc9][0x82]$[0xf7][0xa4][0xf7]G0[0xc6][0x84]c[0x90]I[0x8f]![0x86][0x81][0xc2][0xd8][0xd0][0xb8][0x12][0x86][0xc0]7"1iX[0xdc][0x4]A[0x90][0xf][0xe5]^[0x80][0x96][0xa0][0x88][0xa3]<[0x8b]r?[0x98][0xbd]b[0xd2][0xc][0xdb][0xaf][0x86][0xe9][0x95]P[0xcd][0x7][0xa0][0x14][0x1c][0xe1][\r][0x10]i[0x5][0x16][0x1a]9[0xa1]X[0xc5]8[0xd5]L[0xf0][0xd7][0xb2]x[0xcc][0xc9][0x99][0xe6][0xf3]C^D[0x17][0xf7]$[0x9f][0xd6][0x8a]r[0x9c][0xf2][0x13][0xd1][0x8f]P[0xf0][0xdb][0x2][0xea]#|[0xb2]g[0xee][0xcd][0xab][0xb5][0xaa](g^?[0xc3]}[0xdf]i[0x3][0xd3]..[0x10]N[0xae][0xdb
```

Comment: what mime-type/content-type are you requesting in the headers?

Comment: @Robert Rowntree, I'm sending "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8"

Comment: U r getting 'application/...' In the response. That may be why the wire logger dumps hex.

Comment: that is whats on the wire in the response . so evidently, you did not send headers indicating that you would Accept "text"

Comment: @Robert Rowntree, that makes sense.  We're using mock for the response and it's probably hard coding the type. Did you use a Hex to String converter online?  I tried using one but got a bunch of special characters.

Comment: i was just saying that you can use the headers to suggest to server, what content-type u will accept in the response ( ask 4 text and u may see the logger logs text)

Answer (score 0):

> > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate

the above in your req headers causes the symptoms u describe because of the following:

server may use decorator to GZIP the response before it goes on the WIRE

your response process should be decorate with [interceptor todo](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientGZipContentCompression.java) the GUNZip.

No idea what state this leaves the WIRE logger in.

I just had to add the interceptor to some of my requests at 'parse.com' and noticed this. 
I dont know yet what state the logger is left in. U may have to look more at that. But should review your response interceptor as it may involve same thing.

My responses (those gzip'd that show in WIRE logger asHEX)  just were hanging when they appeared in Android app from parse.com. Just fixed with the wrapper on the response entity as you see in code link.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using apache http. So logging in "org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire" is escaping special characters with hex.

```
    private void wire(final String header, final InputStream inStream)
  throws IOException {
    final StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    int ch;
    while ((ch = inStream.read()) != -1) {
        if (ch == 13) {
            buffer.append("[\\r]");
        } else if (ch == 10) {
                buffer.append("[\\n]\"");
                buffer.insert(0, "\"");
                buffer.insert(0, header);
                log.debug(id + " " + buffer.toString());
                buffer.setLength(0);
        } else if ((ch < 32) || (ch > 127)) {
            buffer.append("[0x");
            buffer.append(Integer.toHexString(ch));
            buffer.append("]");
        } else {
            buffer.append((char) ch);
        }
    }
    if (buffer.length() > 0) {
        buffer.append('\"');
        buffer.insert(0, '\"');
        buffer.insert(0, header);
        log.debug(id + " " + buffer.toString());
    }
}
```